# Wordpress not reflecting phpMyAdmin database changes unless I log in

Tags: wordpress

this is I think a really unusual case. A little backstory, I outsourced a PSD to WP project a few months ago, but not currently working with the developer anymore as he stopped replying to my support questions. I'm trying to solve this on my own before I give this to the client, as I have no more budget to hire another developer.

I have two problems, first is I couldn't access the WP dashboard even though my login is an admin account. Been trying to solve this through numerous google searches and blog posts but to no avail, I couldn't fix it.

Here goes my main problem: So I finally found a way how to update the content on the site using the phpMyAdmin backend database. (good thing I know HTML CSS)

I managed to update the content, but when I tested the site using incognito window and other profiles / browsers, the changes from phpMyAdmin does not reflect on the site. I tried logging in, and weirdly, the changes are there. I log out, changes are there.

I just find it really weird and a hassle that I have to log in to see those changes. It's a client facing site, and the changes are really important so I hope someone has experienced this before and can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you disable the plugins?  There is probably a cache in place

Comment: Is there any way I could do this in phpMyAdmin? I can't access the wp dashboard

Comment: If you can get into phpmyadmin.  Why don't you just add yourself as an admin to the WP site via MYSQL?  Otherwise, change the folder names of your plugins via FTP, and they should deactivate themselves.

Comment: As I've mentioned in my question, I've followed steps to add myself as an admin but for some reason, I still can't access the dashboard. 

edit: I'm using godaddy's managed wordpress as hosting

Comment: I'll try that FTP solution tomorrow. I'm not really a developer so there might be some things I'm missing to help narrow the problem down...

Comment: Can you post the steps you followed? Maybe you are missing something.  Just add that to your question